# spring-cloud-gateway global filter to extract security info from an access token and relay it to downstream services

Tags: spring, oauth-2.0, cloud, global, gateway

I have been using the spring-cloud-gateway as a ResourceServer and for a specific implementation,want to extract some information like say, roles of the user,from the JWT access token it receives to downstream services.

I did that in a GatewayFliter implementation by getting the principal from the exchange and casting that to an Authentication and then getting the user's roles from the token.
But now I want to do that in a GlobalFilter so that I can move this 'security' functionality to a global level,but the same block of code from the GatewayFilter does not work in a GlobalFilter.

This is the code block I was referring to:

```
      exchange.getPrincipal()
       .filter(principal -> principal instanceof Authentication)
       .cast(Authentication.class)
       .map(authentication->extractAuthoritiesAndSetThatToRequest(exchange, 
        authentication))
       .defaultIfEmpty(exchange).flatMap(chain::filter);
```

The above block works in a class that extends an **AbstractGatewayFilterFactory**and the method *extractAuthoritiesAndSetThatToRequest* executes,but not in a class that implements  **GlobalFilter**.
I want the same functionality in a GlobalFilter.
Perhaps I am missing something.Could you please help?

Comment: How does your `authentication->extractAuthoritiesAndSetThatToRequest(exchange, 
authentication)` looks like and how you are setting the header?